# PL/SQL error reference to uninitialised collection error even when its initialised

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL script which used nested table. Below is the sample code.

```
type rec is record 
(
--col data types here
)

type rec_table is table of rec;
v_rec_table rec_table := rec_table(); --initialising here.
arr_size integer := 0;   --edit 1
...
...
begin
...
...
open cursor;
loop
    fetch cursor bulk collect into v_rec_table limit arr_size; --edit

if nvl(v_rec_table.last,0) > 0 --it shows error is here.
then
...
...
end if;
```

The error is ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection. Please help me debug this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies since i did not post whole code. The error occurred because i did not add `index by` to two columns in the record definition.

After reading through few articles i found my flaw.

Answer (score 2):

If would help if you posted complete (sample) code (instead of "...").

Here's an example based on Scott's schema which works OK (your *error* line is line 14):

```
SQL> declare
  2    type rec is record (id number);
  3    type rec_table is table of rec;
  4    v_rec_table rec_table := rec_table();
  5
  6    cursor c1 is select empno from emp;
  7  begin
  8    open c1;
  9    loop
 10      exit when c1%notfound;
 11      fetch c1 bulk collect into v_rec_table;
 12    end loop;
 13    dbms_output.put_line('last = ' || v_rec_table.last);
 14    if nvl(v_rec_table.last, 0) > 0 then
 15       dbms_output.put_line('last exists');
 16    end if;
 17    close c1;
 18  end;
 19  /
last = 12
last exists

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Though, I'm not sure what's that LOOP used for, as you could have done it as

```
SQL> declare
  2    type rec is record (id number);
  3    type rec_table is table of rec;
  4    v_rec_table rec_table := rec_table();
  5  begin
  6    select empno bulk collect into v_rec_table from emp;
  7    dbms_output.put_line('last = ' || v_rec_table.last);
  8  end;
  9  /
last = 12

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: i added this line dbms_output.put_line(NVL (v_rec_table.LAST, 0));  before if condition which prints the number which i used as limit in bulk collect statement. This indicates the last function works and returns the index correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Although your problem is not reproducible, there are few things I found could be improved in your code.

If you are using a `bulk collect`, the collection is initialised automatically and hence, this line is not required

```
v_rec_table rec_table := rec_table();
```

Also, as @Littlefoot mentioned, `LOOP` is not required unless you are using the `LIMIT` clause.

You may use the `COUNT` collection function  instead of `nvl(v_rec_table.last,0)`

```
v_rec_table.count
```

Instead of defining a record type and bulk collecting into it, you may define a collection of `cursor%ROWTYPE`;

```
CURSOR cur is SELECT column1,column2 FROM tablename;
type    rec_table is table of cur%ROWTYPE;
v_rec_table rec_table;
```

Comment: I do use a limit clause which i added to my original question. We have a similar script which works but this script which was modified from the working script throws this error.

Comment: @ArunKumar : Do you know for sure the error is caused by the line you are showing? There could be some other issue which we may not know because the code in your question is incomplete. So, try to debug  the differences added after the modification and give us more information which could help us identify the issue.

Comment: The issue was on another line which i thought was fine. Please see my answer.